# Issue with email sent incorrectly without file attachment

Tags: android, email

I read and re-read my code but it looks fine to me but the email is sent without the attachment.

I even re-read the file (readFile()) before calling the email activity.

What is wrong with my code:

```
   private void sndRecMail(){
    btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
    btnSend.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String subject = "file vendors";

            Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            email.setType("*/*");
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"xxxxxxx@yahoo.fr"});
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

            String dir = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
            fi = new File(dir, "vendors.txt");
            if (!fi.exists() || !fi.canRead())
                return;

            readFile();  // check if file is not empty and readable!!!

            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(fi);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Select Email Client"));

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: `readFile();`  1 What sense does it have if you do not check the return value and return if not readable?

Comment: `getFilesDir()` is private internal memory for your app. The email app cannot read from it.

Comment: 1st comment: I was lazy:I checked through the debugger. 2nd comment: I think that is the issue. I

Comment: ...I'll check it. Thanks!

Comment: confirmed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should include these permissions as well:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Also try:

```
Uri.parse("file://" + fi);
```